# What is the exact difference between 'tty' and a 'console'?

Tags: terminal, iterm, console

I know the general idea of console, tty as here explains https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con

But when run `who` (using iTerm2) I got these and I don't understand the difference here. BTW, I open 2 tabs in iTerms

```
ws ➤ who                                                                                                              
qiulang  console  Dec  5 17:47
qiulang  ttys002  Dec  5 17:48
qiulang  ttys004  Dec  6 10:41
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console is your physical computer and the various tty are virtual terminals.

Each tab or window of a terminal emulator like *iTerm2.app* or *Terminal.app* will connect to a different tty.  MacOS works the same as this quote from [one of the answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4131) on your linked question:

> So when you look to a "text window" on your linux system (under X11) you are looking to: a terminal emulator, connected to a virtual terminal, identified by a tty file, inside which runs a shell.

It is more clear what is happening if you run [who](https://ss64.com/osx/who.html) with `who -a` (to show all details) and if you also use the [tty](https://ss64.com/osx/tty.html) command (which returns the current terminal).

---

**An example**

Here I rebooted at 13:20, left it on the FileVault password entry screen until 13:25 then opened a *Terminal.app* session at 13:29.

```
Last login: Fri Dec  6 13:25:54 on console
A1398% tty
/dev/ttys000
A1398%
```

You can see the last logon was 13:25:54 on console (when FileVault unlocked startup disk) and *Terminal.app* is running on /dev/ttys000.

Next at 13:30 opened a *iTerm2.app* session:

```
Last login: Fri Dec  6 13:29:06 on ttys000
A1398% tty
/dev/ttys001
A1398% who -a
reboot   ~        Dec  6 13:25   .           1
hali     console  Dec  6 13:25 00:04        97
hali     ttys000  Dec  6 13:29 00:01       577
hali     ttys001  Dec  6 13:30   .         600
   .       run-level 3
A1398%
```

You can see the last logon is shown to be 13:29:06 on ttys000 (when *Terminal.app* was opened) and *iTerm2.app* connected at 13:30 to /dev/ttys001.

`who -a` shows

- console connecting at 13:25 (when password was entered and FileVault unlocked startup disk).
- ttys000 connecting at 13:29 (when *Terminal.app* was opened).
- ttys001 connecting at 13:30 (when this session of *iTerm2* was opened).

If you boot into [single user mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573) and type `tty` you will see the result `/dev/console` (`who` is not available)